# Grouping authors' papers in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

What is the best way to set up a bibliography that deals with multiple papers by the same authors as follows:

J.M. Bismut:
[1] Paper 1
[2] Paper 2
[3] Paper 3

E.B. Dynkin:
[1] Paper 1
[2] Paper 2

with citations such as 'Bismut [3]' and 'Dynkin [1]', as opposed to the typical layout of

[1] J.M. Bismut - Paper 1
[2] J.M. Bismut - Paper 2
[3] J.M. Bismut - Paper 3
[4] E.B. Dynkin - Paper 1
[5] E.B. Dynkin - Paper 2